# Generating a random set of numbers with a fixed total, excluding the middle values of the range

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, math

I'm trying to create an array of integers that fit within specific rules, and my current method seems pretty slow.

Can someone help me optimize it?

Rules:

1. Start with a total value, i.e. 179
2. Divide into two integers, i.e. A=90, B=89
3. Calculate an array of X integers where:

   - No array value can equal A or B
   - The total of all array values must be equal to the total value
   - Array values are randomly created within a specified range.
   - Multiple array items can have the same value (but not all items!)
   - Array count (X) can get as high as 100 (totalValue will also increase as the array count increases)

Here is my current (slow) code:

```
-(void)calcArray{
   // set the total value of the array integers
   NSInteger totalValue=179;
   // set the maximum value for any integer in the array
   NSInteger maxRange=totalValue * 0.7;
   // set the array count
   NSInteger arrayMax=30;
   // split the total value
   NSInteger glA=totalValue/2;
   NSInteger glB=ceil(totalValue+1)/2;

   NSInteger tmpTTL;
   NSMutableArray *vals=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   do{
      NSLog(@"*** STARTING DO ***");
      [vals removeAllObjects];
      tmpTTL=0;
      for(short i=0; i<arrayMax; i++){
         [vals addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:arc4random_uniform(maxRange)+1]];
      }
      for(short i=0; i<arrayMax; i++){
         if([[vals objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]==gl1 ||
            [[vals objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]==gl2){
            tmpTTL=0;
            break;
         }else{
            tmpTTL+=[[vals objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
         }
      }
   }while(tmpTTL!=totalValue);
   NSLog(@"*** DONE DO ***");

   // print the array values
   for(short i=0; i<arrayMax; i++){
      NSLog(@"NEW CALC val: %li",[[vals objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't select all the numbers at once and then start over if one is bad; pick them one at a time and only add each to the array if fits your criteria. Note also that selecting a number bigger than `totalValue - tmpTTL` would be a waste of time; you should refine your selection each time you ask for a random number.

Comment: Josh - You might think that would work, but you end up subtracting your values from the total as you go, and then you can end up with a final value that fails criteria 3-1.

Comment: Then add a backtrack condition if you get stuck.

Comment: One other thing to consider is that if you choose the first array entry with uniform probability over the permitted range, you might end up with non-uniform probability distributions for the remaining array entries. If you are looking for an efficient way to replicate the results of choosing all X variables uniformly and then throwing away the results that don't add up to the desired total (which will be almost all results), you may want to know the probability distribution of each entry in the successful trials. And then condition each new entry on the ones already found.

Comment: Just the general observation that this appears to be a variation of the "bin packing problem".

Comment: Hot Licks - Yes, in fact I wrote a version of 'bin packing' to test it and while it is very fast, the distribution of values over a small number of bins is extremely even (bell curve anyone?). For example if the total value desired is 120 in 3 bins, it is common to get a distribution like '39,42,39' rather than a preferred distribution of '3,97,20'